# Not able to run my java program to construct BST

Tags: java, tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to construct BST From PreOrder And inorder

```
// Construct Binary Tree From Inorder And Preorder

public class Solution {
    public TreeNode buildTree(ArrayList<Integer> A, ArrayList<Integer> B) {
        return buildTreeUtil(A,0,A.size()-1,B,0,B.size()-1);
    }
    public TreeNode buildTreeUtil(ArrayList<Integer> inOrder,int inOrderStart,int inOrderStop,
                        ArrayList<Integer> preOrder,int preOrderStart,int preOrderStop){

    if(inOrderStart > inOrderStop || preOrderStart>preOrderStop){
        return null;
    }
    TreeNode root = new TreeNode(preOrder.get(preOrderStart));
    int index = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<inOrder.size()-1;i++){
        if(inOrder.get(i)==preOrder.get(preOrderStart)){
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    root.left = buildTreeUtil(inOrder,inOrderStart,index-1,
                            preOrder,preOrderStart+1,preOrderStart+(index-inOrderStart));
    root.right = buildTreeUtil(inOrder,index+1,inOrderStop,
                            preOrder,preOrderStart+index-inOrderStart+1,preOrderStop);
    return root;
    }
}
```

It's giving exception

> Index out of bound

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated to the IndexOutOfBoundsException, but the following line of code is improperly using the equality operator == to compare two Integer instances, instead it should use the .equals() method:

Bad code:

```
if(inOrder.get(i)==preOrder.get(preOrderStart)){
```

Correct code:

```
if(inOrder.get(i).equals(preOrder.get(preOrderStart))) {
```

The IndexOutOfBoundsException is likely occurring because the following lines of code are not protected against preOrderStart and preOrderStop parameter values that are negative or greater than the ArrayList's size()-1:

```
root.left = buildTreeUtil(inOrder,inOrderStart,index-1,
                       preOrder,preOrderStart+1,preOrderStart+(index-inOrderStart));
root.right = buildTreeUtil(inOrder,index+1,inOrderStop,
                       preOrder,preOrderStart+index-inOrderStart+1,preOrderStop);
```

Think about what happens in the code above if the variable index has a value of 0.  The parameter index-1 will get a value of -1.